# Extension download error:Python 27 not detected

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7-x64, python-module, failed-installation

I need the pywin32 extension for Python 2.7, and I tried downloading it from different sources like SourceForge and got the same error each time when ran it and opened the blue 'Powered by Python' window:

```
Python 27 directory not found.
```

So I am not able to install the module.How can I make sure the installer detects the Python 2.7 directory, which I have installed.I did the same thing with another module and it took several tries before it finally worked.I am running Windows 7.

Comment: where is your `python27` directory?

Comment: IT's possible that either the python or module is 64 bit, and the other is 32 bit (often the module will be 32 bit). open python and do `import platform` followed by `platform.architecture()` to see which your python is, 32-bit is best.

Comment: No, I made sure that it was 64 bit, the one that I need for my OS.

Comment: you can run 32-bit Python fine on a 64-bit OS, but a large number of Python modules won't run on a 64-bit python.

Comment: what do you get when you use `platform.architecture()`?

Answer (score 0):

Credits to scironic.

```
import platform
platform.architecture()
```

This code returned that I am running 32 bit Python, even though my OS was 64 bit. So I realized that my mistake had been that I, thinking I was running 64 bit Python on my 64 bit Os, had downloaded the 64 bit module.I downloaded a 32 bit module and it was installed successfully.